# Google Oauth 2 PHP - Google calendar

Tags: php, authentication, calendar, google-oauth

I try to make an application with Google Calendar. I'm using this code (found  [here](http://www.daimto.com/accessing-google-calendar-with-php-oauth2) )
, but I have some issues.

```
<?php  
require_once 'google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/autoload.php';   
require_once 'google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Service/Calendar.php';  
//require_once 'CalendarHelper.php';  
session_start(); 
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("name");
$client->setDeveloperKey("devkey");  
$client->setClientId('clientid');
$client->setClientSecret('cliendsecret');
$client->setRedirectUri('https://localhost/testGoogle/index.php');
$client->setAccessType('offline');   // Gets us our refreshtoken

$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'));


//For loging out.
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
}


// Step 2: The user accepted your access now you need to exchange it.
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    echo "test";
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);  
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

// Step 1:  The user has not authenticated we give them a link to login    
if (!isset($_SESSION['token'])) {

    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

    print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";

}    
// Step 3: We have access we can now create our service
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    print "<a class='logout' href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?logout=1'>LogOut</a><br>";  

    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);    
    $calendarList  = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();;
    print_r($calendarList);
    while(true) {
        foreach ($calendarList->getItems() as $calendarListEntry) {
            echo $calendarListEntry->getSummary()."<br>\n";
        }
        $pageToken = $calendarList->getNextPageToken();
        if ($pageToken) {
            $optParams = array('pageToken' => $pageToken);
            $calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList($optParams);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

When I click on the button "Connect me!", I choose my google account, I accept the required permissions, and after:

- If I put **https**://localhost/testGoogle/index.php as the redirect URI, I have the error:

  > The webpage is not available" with this error in the console: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
- If I put **http**://localhost/testGoogle/index.php as the redirect URI, I have  PHP error:

  > Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_IO_Exception' with message 'Failed to connect to accounts.google.com port 443: Connection refused' in C:\wamp\www\testGoogle\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\IO\Curl.php on line 116
  >
  > ( ! ) Google_IO_Exception: Failed to connect to accounts.google.com port 443: Connection refused in C:\wamp\www\testGoogle\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\IO\Curl.php on line 116

What's wrong with my code?